# ID all the clips in Samsung Galaxy Gear commercial?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Loved this commercial. I have a bunch of them, but some are stumping me.

0. Don't know
1. Get Smart
2. Predator
3. Inspector Gadget
4. Don’t know
5. Jetsons
6. Get Smart
7. Dick Tracy
8. Flash Gordon?
9. Don’t know
10. Star Trek The Motion Picture
11. Power Rangers
12. Flash Gordon
13. Flintstones
14. Knight Rider
15. Don’t know
16. Get Smart
17. Thunderbirds
18. Babylon 5?
19. Dick Tracy
20. Knight Rider
21. Babylon 5?

Comment: 16 is Johnny Sokko and and his Flying Robot. Not sure about the others.

Comment: I adjusted the numbering.  There's a short one right at the start.

Comment: Your video is unavailable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Number 1 is Johnny Sokko and his Flying Robot.
Number 5 is Babylon 5.
Number 9 is Power Rangers (again).
Number 10 is Marine Boy (Thanks gnovice).
Number 16 is Johnny Sokko and his Flying Robot (Thanks gnovice).
Number 19 is Power Rangers (yet again).
Number 22 is Babylon 5.

Comment: what about number 10?

Comment: @JackBNimble That's the one I don't know... I know it's an old Japanese thing.

Comment: Found [this site](http://www.popisms.com/TelevisionCommercial/83038/Samsung-Commercial-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Gear-2.aspx) which seems to cover most of them. Number 10 is Marine Boy, though they incorrectly list Team America: World Police instead of the Thunderbirds. They also missed Babylon 5.